# Playwright headed mode nightly (firefox) browser is not responding works fine with chromium and webkit

Tags: playwright

I am using

playwright version 1.42.0

C#
I have an issue running a test in headed mode with the Firefox (nightly) browser (firefox-1438). Every browser works fine (chromium, webkit, edge) except nightly in headed mode. In headless mode nightly works fine. Well, I am not receiving any error and testing is executed without a defect.

Comment: please write a MWE